# Backbone js to create a multiple views and pagination

Tags: backbone.js

I need a example to create a backbone js example to show the table in grid or list view and with pagination. 
Can anybody help me with example?

Answer (score 0):

There are live examples of building this type of functionality on the [backbone.paginator](https://github.com/backbone-paginator/backbone.paginator) plugin github repository.